# Read objects from a .class file

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, javassist

I'm trying to use Javassist in order to get all the instantiated objects in a .class file, however, I can't seem to find the way to do so, so I ask, is there any way to get, for example, an array of Objects from a .class file?

Here is the class from which I would like to get the instantiated objects:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(new Widget());
        System.out.println(new Widget("width", 80));
        System.out.println(new Widget("height", 30));
        System.out.println(new Widget("height", 20, "width", 90));

    }

}
```

Widget's constructor is simply

`public Widget(Object ...args) {}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.class file does not contain instantiated objects. They are created at runtime, when the method `main()` is called.

For the given example, there is no way to collect instantiated objects even at runtime.